# Sorting files with the same first 3 letters, than deleting the older files?

Tags: c#

I had a question last week, and you quickly alleviated any concern that it would roadblock me, hoping that you can help a beginner program once more!

I'm trying to automate one of my daily mundane tasks and it's being quite a bugger, I think mainly because I'm not taking the correct approach.

Each morning I go through a system directory that houses many files with the same prefix, and a generated number following it. I have to sort alphabetically first, then remove the oldest versions of that file.

Here's an example pic of my directory: [http://i.imgur.com/5l2Am.png](https://i.imgur.com/5l2Am.png)

I was going to approach this situation by just sorting the files by name and comparing the first 3 letters to the following file, and if they were identical I would delete (or move to a backup folder) the second file, until they didn't match any longer, and I would move onto the next prefix as the comparator.

The problem with this though I found, is that they aren't always sorted correctly, and I risk deleting the wrong files.

Has anyone had experience with something of this nature? In my head and on VS I can put the pieces all there, but just can't seem to link it together, mainly because I've never ventured into the system.IO class before, but I want to learn!

Any advice is appreciated, and if you want to see my futile attempts I'll gladly share them :P.

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: It seems to me like a good task for Windows Powershell.

Comment: @MartyIX Agreed. Powershell was BORN for this sort of task.

Comment: I'll check Powershell out right now!

Comment: Meanwhile, can you explain what you mean by "not sorted correctly"?  Even if powershell does the job here, it's probably worth figuring out what went wrong there.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) to retrieve the filenames.  I suspect that your sorting problem is probably due to casing - in C#, string sorts, by default, as case sensitive, but the file system is not.

I'd recommend loading up the list of files, then sorting them yourself, in C#, prior to processing them:

```
 List<string> files = Directory.GetFiles(myDirectory)
     .Select(file => file.ToLower()) // To lower case
     .OrderBy(file => file) // Sort the files
     .ToList();

 // Process the files here...
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary indexed by the three character prefix.

When you reach a file, check the dictionary for a value:

- if none exists, keep the file and add it to the dictionary, where the key is the prefix and the value is the number following the prefix
- if one exists, but has an older "number" value, archive the old one, keep the newer one and update the dictionary to have the new number
- if one exists, but has a newer "number" value, archive the old one, keep the newer one and the dictionary is already up to date at this point.

No sorting necessary.

EDIT: Adding example:

```
public static void ProcessDirectory(string directoryPath)
    {
        IDictionary<string,string> prefixDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        if (Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
        {
            foreach(string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath))
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                string fileDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
                if (fileName.Length>=3)
                {                        
                    string prefix = fileName.Substring(0, 3);
                    string rightPart = fileName.Substring(3, fileName.Length - 3);
                    if (!prefixDictionary.ContainsKey(prefix))
                    {
                        prefixDictionary[prefix] = rightPart;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string fileToArchive = null;
                        string storedRightPart = prefixDictionary[prefix];
                        // using string compare, but you could test file date or
                        // or parse the right part as a number if you only cared about
                        // files with numbers on the right.
                        if (String.Compare(storedRightPart,rightPart)<0)
                        {
                            prefixDictionary[prefix] = rightPart;
                            fileToArchive = Path.Combine(fileDirectory,prefix+storedRightPart);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fileToArchive = filePath;
                        }

                        if (fileToArchive != null)
                        {
                            // perform the archive here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think I follow you, I'm not the most confident coder yet, but I'm learning about the proper utilization of dictionaries. I think I roger you loud and clear.

Let's see if I can mock up some code and see if I get this bugger a little more 'together'.

Thank you!!

Comment: Would you mind dropping some code in here to get me started, I feel like a toddler with this stuff, maybe I should start on an easier project, but if I could complete this, I could spend my freed up time learning such things :P.

Thank you either way,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

You get get an array of FileInfo objects, which contain a lot of the metadata about the files, which would let you sort them. It also allows you to delete.

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:/yourPath");
FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
```

From there, you can sort `files` by `CreationTime` or `Name` or whatever. To delete one, just use the `Delete` method on the FileInfo class.